# Swift Firestore Generate Document ID before creating a document

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to generate a document id to use on two documents in seperate collections.

I am able to achieve this in an Angular PWA, but I'm now working it into an iOS app.

Basically an appointment document is added to a user, then a top level document is created for ease of display and notifications using the same document id

> users/uid/appointments/newID
>
> appointments/uid/appointment/newID

All of this takes place in the same ViewController, so in the code I need to generate a temporary document id to use as the id in both collections.

I hope that makes sense....

would let `tempId = db.document().documentID` do the trick?

Comment: So far I am trying the following, I have created the appointments document in the users collection and retrieved the document id and placed that in a variable, tempID. I have put the tempID in a new collection reference like so, `myRef.document(tempID).setData([myArray])` but Firestore is still generating a new id.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to suss it all out.

After creating my collection reference, let's call it myRef, I did the following:

```
myRef = db.collection("collection_name")
secondRef = db.collection("second_collection")

let tempId = myRef.document().documentid

myRef.document(tempId).setData(myDictionary)
secondRef.document(tempId).setData(otherDictionary)
```

That helped create the duplicate document id's i needed.

Hope this helps with someone else...

Cheers

Michael